# Sorting logic configured by string order

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, comparator

I have a comma separated string which holds the sort criteria for sorting a list of Students:

```
Input:
String sortOrder = "height, weight, age"
List<student> students;
```

Each of the elements above are Comparators on the student object that sort the Student object with some complex logic. I need to know how best to translate the sort order as it appears in the sortOrder string and activate the matching comparators in that order. So for the above example, the height comparator would run first and the age one last.

Comment: "So for the above example, the height comparator would run first and the age one last.".  Sorting doesn't work that way.  You sort by height.  When the heights are equal, you sort by weight.  When the weights are equal, you sort by age.

Comment: Please clarify: do you want a single sort with three (or whatever number) levels, as @GilbertLeBlanc described? Or three different sorts, performed in the order listed in the `String`?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom I was looking for the latter.

Comment: This is your *third* question about the same thing in one day. You should start focusing on explaining what you actually want to do in one question instead of opening new questions. Please, remove the other questions and then edit this one, adding more information about your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a `HashMap` mapping these words to `Comparator` objects. Then use the Comparators for sorting

```
Map<String, Comparator<student>> comparators = new HashMap<>();
```

after you add `Comparator` objects to `comparators` like this :

```
comparators.put("height", Comparator.comparingDouble(student::getHeight));
```

If you would like to perform different sorts consecutively, just go through the words in the `sortOrder` and apply e.g.

```
for (String comp : sortOrder.split(", "))
    Collections.sort(students, comparators.get(comp));
```

Comment: This will not work.  You will end up with the list sorted by the last field in the input string.  You should instead combine all comparators using `thenComparing`:  `Comparator<Student> comp  = Pattern.compile(", ") .splitAsStream(sortOrder) .map(comparators::get) .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing) .get();`

Comment: Right and wrong, @Misha. This answer won't work, correct. But this is more than a simple sort problem, despite the title. See comments on the question and other questions asked by OP today. It's confusing.

Comment: @Misha OP mentioned in the comments that this is precisely what he wants, 3 different sorts 1 after the other. He may want to do things with the list before it gets re-sorted e.g. print it. As a matter I was writing a `Comparator` with a more reasonable behaviour until I saw the OP's comments and then wrote this.

Comment: Since `sort` is stable, sorting using comparators in a specific order is equivalent to sorting once using the comparators combined to one in the opposite order…

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom I think it's likely that the OP didn't understand the question when he said he was looking for "the latter".  I looked at his other questions and, I agree, it's unclear what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want, you want to sort the list of students by their heights, then their weight and then their age. But you want this list of property to be dynamic.

This means we need to implement a custom `Comparator` that works with a given property of a given class.

A first implementation could be creating a `Map` where each String property is mapped to an associate `Comparator`. This would be a clean approach (see @Manos Nikolaidis' answer, and Misha's comment, for this implementation).

A true dynamic solution is possible using a little bit of reflection: first the declared field having the given name of the given class is retrieved. It is set accessible since this field is most likely private. Finally, a `Comparator` comparing the value of this field for each student is returned. This code assumes blindly that the target property is in fact `Comparable` (otherwise, why would we want to compare using this field?).

```
private static <U> Comparator<U> comparingProperty(String property, Class<U> clazz) {
    try {
        Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(property);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return Comparator.comparing(s -> {
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Comparable<Object> comparable = (Comparable<Object>) field.get(s);
                return comparable;
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            }
        });
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

Once that we have this utility comparator, we can sort a list of student easily. A stream of the sort properties is created by splitting around `","` and trimming the results. Then, each property is mapped to its corresponding `Comparator` and, finally, this stream is reduced by combining all of the comparators together with `Comparator::thenComparing`:

```
students.sort(Stream.of(sortOrder.split(","))
                    .map(String::trim)
                    .map(s -> comparingProperty(s, Student.class))
                    .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)
                    .get()
             );
```